# como dejar por defecto un option de select

Tags: html5

hola necesito mostrar ya seleccionada una opcion del select, quiero que muestre seleccionada la opcion de Seleccione sueldo

Este es el codigo que tengo pero aun no me muestra seleccionado nada, me muestra el select vacio

```
select#selectsueldoedit.form-control(style='border: 1px solid #ccc;border-radius: 4px;padding: 6px 12px;height: 34px;line-height: 1.42857143;font-size: 14px;color: ')
          option(value='Seleccione sueldo', selected='selected') Seleccione sueldo
          each sueldo in datos.sueldos
             option(value=''+sueldo.pk) #{sueldo.sueldo}
```

Comment: Agrega mas especificaciones como que framework usas, no creo que esto solo sea HTML5

Answer (score 1):

```html
<select id="sueldo">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option selected="selected">3</option>
  <option>4</option>
  <option>5</option>
</select>
```

A la opción que quieres aparezca "predeterminada" debes colocarle el atributo `selected="selected"`. Si estás usando otro lenguaje de programación podrías indicar cual